# .net Calendar requiredFieldValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, requiredfieldvalidator

Is it possible to add a requiredFieldValidator to a calendar?
For example I have a submit button and if it is clicked without selecting a date red text should come up saying please select date first.

I know one way is to simply check for selectedDate in c# code but can I create a requiredFieldValidator as for textboxes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think No but you can add a requiredFieldValidator and associate it with a hidden TextBox (I mean CSS display:none) on the page and bind the TextBox Text property to the SelectedDate of the calender

Comment: Yes thats what I was thinking also. Thanks

Comment: How would you do that? I've tried `Text='<%# Bind("Calendar1.SelectedDate") %>'`, but the text box (which is currently visible for testing) *isn't* being populated.

Answer (score 0):

use textbox along with [ajax Toolkit calendar extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) and set required fields validator for this textbox control..you can Download ajax toolkit from [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/download.ashx). and add refrence of that dll to your project..

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late for an answer, but I did it this way,

Add a textbox with css display:none and get the selectedDate from the server side on calender_DayRender

```
 protected void calenderPrefDate_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    txtCalenderDate.Text = calenderPrefDate.SelectedDate.ToString();
    if(calenderPrefDate.SelectedDate.ToString() == "01/01/0001 00:00:00")
    {
        txtCalenderDate.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

if condition is added because when the page is refreshed, the textbox picks up "01/01/0001 00:00:00" as nothing is selected. and controlToValidate the textbox. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please place the requiredfieldvalidator control and attach it to the textbox that receives the date from asp:calendar. 
Hope this would help..
Sample Code

(e.g.) txtDOB is the textbox

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question. Where is the sample code?